# Time complexity for a "Palindrome Number" solution

Tags: python

This is a solution for solving LeetCode problem #9 Palindrome Number.
I'm thinking about the time complexity of the solution. I try to understand the time complexity with examples.

Say for a 3-digit number, it goes through the while loop twice.

For a 6-digit number, it goes through the while loop 3 times.

I conclude the number increases 1000 times, while loop increases by 1.

So what's the time complexity?

Could anyone please explain to me? Thank you so much.

```
def isPalindrome(self, x):
    if x < 0 or (x > 0 and x % 10 == 0): return False
    half = 0
    while x > half:
        half, x = half * 10 + x % 10, x / 10
    return x in (half, half / 10)
```

Comment: `(..., ..., ...)` usually forms a tuple (or a generator). You can very well use the `in` operator for tuples (or lists, etc.). This is what happens here: you're checking if x is in (some_value, some_value/10).

Comment: Parentheses don't form tuples: commas do. The parentheses only serve to prevent the comma from being treated differently based on context. E.g. `f(3, 5)` calls `f` with 2 arguments, 3 and 5. `f((3,5))` calls `f` with a single tuple argument.

Comment: @chepner: You're right, I was not precise enough.

Comment: In this case, `return x in half, half/10` would attempt to return a tuple consisting of the result of `x in half` and the value `half/10`.

Comment: You should avoid radically changing the nature of your question as it invalidates comments and answers provided on its original form.  You question started out with understanding of the `half` variable and has now mutated into a complexity consideration

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll create a new post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`x in (half, half/10)` returns True if `x` is one of the two values in the tuple. It's equivalent to

```
x == half or x == half/10
```